# Silex: Can I mount controller providers recursively?

Tags: php, routes, silex

I wanted to group my api routes as follows:

```
$app->mount('/api/v1.0', function($api) use($app) {
    $api->mount('/documents', new DocumentsApiControllerProvider());
});
```

where the **`DocumentsApiControllerProvider`** is defined like that:

```
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Api\ControllerProviderInterface;
use App\Controllers\DocumentsApiController;

class DocumentsApiControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface {
    public function connect(Application $app) {

        $app['api.documents.controller'] = function() use($app) {
            return new DocumentsApiController();
        };

        $controller = $app['controllers_factory'];
        $controller->get('/folders/{folder_id}/content/pages/{page}', 'api.documents.controller:getPage');

        return $controller;
    }
}
```

This results in the following exception being thrown:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'The "mount" method takes either a "ControllerCollection" instance or callable.'

Whereas non-recursive mounting works as expected:

```
$app->mount('/api/v1.0/documents', new DocumentsApiControllerProvider());
```

There's a discussion regarding the topic: https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/pull/1345, yet I couldn't understand was the ability added or ignored?

How do I achieve this?

**Update**

Well, I decided to mount api routed straight into the **`Silex\Application`** instance (nesting/grouping!), just with the same prefix - **'api/v1.0/'**:

```
$app->mount("/api/v1.0/documents", new DocumentsApiControllerProvider());
$app->mount("/api/v1.0/otherstuff", new OtherStuffApiControllerProvider());
```

Comment: [`ControllerCollection#mount`](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/ControllerCollection.php#L67) doesn't accept instances of `ControllerProviderInterface`. [`Application#mount`](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Application.php#L447) does. But you can't do that like you want, (you need to use the `$app` instead of `$api` to mount the route, but you would need to specify the full prefix, so what's the point on doing that?)

Comment: @Federkun so it could help someone, please add an answer & I'll accept that. Thank you.